# Как реализовать routing в зависимости от значения переменной в Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, аутентификация

Только знакомлюсь с Angular и передо мне встала задача добавить страницу логина. Создал AuthService и реализовал его следующим образом:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private _isLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
  isLoggedIn$ = this._isLoggedIn$.asObservable()

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    this._isLoggedIn$.next(!!token)
  }

  logIn(login: string, password: string){
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/auth", {
      username: login,
      password: password
    }).pipe(
      tap((response: any) => {
        this._isLoggedIn$.next(true)
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.token)
      })
    )
  }
}
```

И у меня есть стандартный роутинг:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: SensorsPageComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

И теперь вопрос, как мне устанавливать routes в зависимости от переменной isLoggedIn$, то есть если она true, то разрешать все маршруты, а если false, то только маршрут со страницей логина?

Comment: Советую обратить внимание на [guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate). По сути в guard надо подписаться на вашу переменную и от нее возвращать уже нужное значение для guard-a.

Answer (score 0):

Очень похожая задача сейчас, решается с помощью 2х инструментов [Guards](https://angdev.ru/doc/angular-routing-guards/) и [HttpInterceptor](https://angdev.ru/doc/angular-http-interceptor/)